# Movilizer - Splash screen android

Tags: android, mobile, movilizer

When I try to customize the client Splash screen the following issue occurs:

I created a 480x800 image within the limits of 512kb as instructed by the customization guidelines.
When I set the image on a android client with a screen resolution of 1080x1920 it doesn't get stretched to full screen.

It happend to a Sony Xperia and HTC One M7 device (both 1080x1920), iOS devices show it correctly (fullscreen). am I doing something wrong?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange](http://android.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: jww, it looks like it is a non programming/development related question. In the background it is however programming related, i haven't put my focus on the code for it looks as if the code works properly (the image is visible) thus I don't know what the issue is. It could however be code related why it doesn't show properly therefore I posted it here.

Comment: Interesting how much attention a Movilizer issue gets once the word "android" appears in the title and / or tag :D .... after all it is a Movilizer issue and it is absolutely not off topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue up to 2.3 ... the 2.3 Movilizer Android client solves the problem. In 2.3 there is a change of the layout resource file for splash screens to fill height.

Please note that as we speak this client is not yet released.